# Can I add onClick event to Html.ListBox Razor helper?

Tags: onclick

I created a ListBox in MCV3/Razor View using Html.ListBox helper. I would like to add onClick event to this ListBox, so JavaScript could perform some work.
My question - how to add onClick event to the Html.ListBox helper?

Thanks,

Zalek